# How to extend ArgumentPluginBase and have it recognized by Views?

Tags: views, 8

I'm wanting to create a Views argument plugin that extends ArgumentPluginBase in order to overrides one of the form elements in the buildOptionsForm(). I've pasted my plugin below. However, it doesn't seem to be recognized by Views. How do I make Views aware of this plugin and to make use of it?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_custom_taxonomy_validation\Plugin\views\argument;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\argument\ArgumentPluginBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Resize the override text field.
 *
 * @ingroup views_argument_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsArgument("my_custom_taxonomy_validation_argument")
 *
 */
class MyCustomTaxonomyValidationArgument extends ArgumentPluginBase {

  public function buildOptionsForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::buildOptionsForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['title'] = [
      '#maxlength' => 355,
    ];

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

register it with hook_views_data_alter() in mymodule.views.inc

Something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {

  $data['node_field_data']['my_custom_taxonomy_validation_argument'] = [
    'help' => t('Hello world'),
    'real field' => 'title',
    'argument' => [
      'title' => t('Hello world'),
      'id' => 'my_custom_taxonomy_validation_argument',
      'accept depth modifier' => TRUE,
    ],
    'filter' => [
      'title' => t('title'),
      'id' => 'my_custom_taxonomy_validation_argument',
    ],
  ];
```

}